# Flash/ActionScript: Draw a display object "onto" another

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, graphics, bitmap

### How do I properly draw one vector object onto a specific position of another in ActionScript, accounting for positioning, transparency, etc?

My idea (as suggested e.g. [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-157588.html)) was to use `beginBitmapFill`() and `drawRect`() to draw a bitmap copy (made using `BitmapData.draw`()) of one MovieClip onto the .`graphics` property of the other MovieClip, but this proved more difficult than I thought, mainly for these reasons:

1. <strike>**Transparency is not preserved**: where the source MovieClip is transparent, the target Graphics becomes white. I've tried using a `BlendMode`, but it doesn't help. It seems white pixels are actually copied into the BitmapData. I must be missing something, but I don't know what.</strike> It seems the problem was that the documentation for the `BitmapData` constructor is wrong: transparency does not default to *true*, but to *false*. So if you create a `new BitmapData(x, y, true)` transparency is preserved, otherwise not.
2. **Positioning**. If the source MovieClip is centered (with the center at (0, 0), you have to apply a Matrix to move it when copying it to a BitmapData, or the bitmap will only contain the bottom right of the source MovieClip. Figuring out how much to move it is tricky, and I assume it involved getting the boundaries somehow. (If the source object is perfectly centered within its canvas, you can simply offset it by half its width and height, of course.)
3. **`beginBitmapFill` tiling**. It seems if you don't start the `drawRect`() at (0, 0), the bitmap fill doesn't start from (0, 0) within the bitmap either. This means you have to shift the source bitmap once again, based on where you want to start drawing.

(Then there's other stuff like having to lineStyle(0,0,0) so the drawRect() doesn't draw a border etc.)

All this tricky trouble leads me to believe I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a library somewhere that can help me? Has anyone successfully done this? Perhaps my drawing canvas shouldn't be a Sprite but a Bitmap? But then I don't know how to draw to it using `lineTo`() etc.

**Here's the situation**: I have a Sprite to which I draw using its .graphics, using lineTo() etc. Now I want to use a MovieClip as a brush when drawing (or just place a copy of another MovieClip on the drawing surface), making the other MovieClip part of the graphics of the first one. I can't `addChild`() because then the vector graphics wouldn't interact with the drawn graphics.

---

**EDIT**: [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554631/flash-actionscript-draw-a-display-object-onto-another/554890#554890) has provided a working solution that works perfectly *except* for the fact that it does not apply the **rotation and scaling** applied to the DisplayObject being drawn onto the Graphics surface. This is [Theo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554631/flash-actionscript-draw-a-display-object-onto-another/554890#554890):

```
private function drawOntoGraphics(source : IBitmapDrawable, target : Graphics, position : Point = null) : void
{
    position = position == null ? new Point() : position;
    var bounds : Rectangle = DisplayObject(source).getBounds(DisplayObject(source));
    var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, true, 0x00000000);
    bitmapData.draw(source, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y), null, null, null, true);
    target.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y));
    target.drawRect(bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
}
```

To support rotation and scaling, I assume the following has to be modified:

1. The `Matrix` used in `draw()` should copy the scaling and rotation from the source `DisplayObject`?
2. The `Matrix` used in `beginBitmapFill()` should copy this scaling and rotation as well? Or maybe that would create "double" scaling and rotation?
3. The `drawRect()` coordinates should be modified to match the size of the scaled and rotated `DisplayObject`? Which means `getBounds()` will not be accurate?

---

**EDIT**: Here is a working implementation which supports scaling and rotation, made from all the feedback:

```
static function DrawOntoGraphics(source:MovieClip, target:Graphics, 
        position:Point = null):void {
    var sourceClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(source)) 
        as Class;   
    var sourceCopy:MovieClip = new sourceClass();
    sourceCopy.rotation = source.rotation;
    sourceCopy.scaleX = source.scaleX;
    sourceCopy.scaleY = source.scaleY;
    sourceCopy.graphics.clear();
    var placeholder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    placeholder.addChild(sourceCopy);
    if (!position) 
        position = new Point();
    var bounds:Rectangle = placeholder.getBounds(placeholder);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, 
        true, 0x00000000);
    var drawMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y);
    bitmapData.draw(placeholder, drawMatrix);           
    placeholder.removeChild(sourceCopy);
    var fillMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, bounds.x + position.x, 
        bounds.y + position.y);
    target.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, fillMatrix);
    target.lineStyle(0, 0x00000000, 0);
    target.drawRect(bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y, 
        bounds.width, bounds.height);
    target.endFill();
}
```

---

Somewhat related but not so hot question: [How to put an image (say, PNG) on a graphics in Flex 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261386/how-to-put-an-image-say-png-on-a-graphics-in-flex-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the display objects getBounds function can be a reliable solution to translate the coordinates while drawing :

```
private function drawOntoGraphics(source : IBitmapDrawable, target : Graphics, position : Point = null) : void
{
        position = position == null ? new Point() : position;

        var bounds : Rectangle = DisplayObject(source).getBounds(DisplayObject(source));
        var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, true, 0x00000000);

        bitmapData.draw(source, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y), null, null, null, true);
        target.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y));
        target.drawRect(bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
}
```

In addition to your comments... Below the same method using a **BitmapData** instead of the Graphics object as canvas:

```
private function drawOntoBitmapData(source : IBitmapDrawable, target : BitmapData, position : Point = null) : void
{
    position = position == null ? new Point() : position;
    var bounds : Rectangle = DisplayObject(source).getBounds(DisplayObject(source));
    var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, true, 0x00000000);
    bitmapData.draw(source, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y), null, null, null, true);
    target.draw(bitmapData, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, bounds.x + position.x, bounds.y + position.y));
}
```

Comment: beginBitmapFill() using a Matrix doesn't actually change where on the target Graphics surface the bitmap is drawn - it just shifts the bitmap brush around itself. What I want is to draw a rectangle anywhere on the target Graphics surface, using the bitmap as a brush. Am I making any sense?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the rectangle containing the bitmap to be drawn at an arbitrary position on the target surface. I'm not sure what the "position" parameter in your drawOntoGraphics() does, other than rotate (along x and y) the source bitmap within its own container.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the position to the drawRect() - last line. It seems to work fine now.

Comment: Aha. I see now that the trick is to match the beginBitmapFill() transform Matrix coordinates with the drawRect() coordinates exactly. Your function meets my particular need perfectly. Thanks! (Honestly though, beginBitmapFill() and drawRect() feels like an awkward solution somehow...)

Comment: Yes, well this was a direct answer to you question trying not to sidetrack you on other solutions. Alas if you add a lot of fills you may get glitches. I would reuse the function but instead of drawing on a Graphics object i would do on a Bitmap "canvas". Good luck ; )

Comment: Thanks. The reason I'm drawing on a Graphics is that I draw with lines using lineTo() etc. If I drew on a Bitmap I would have to render everything as BitmapData all the time.

Comment: If you are only using one canvas it wouldn't make much difference in terms of performance using a bitmapData (as target). But maybe you want to still be able to draw vector shapes on the canvas ... I added an example above, give it a try.

Comment: I just realized this solution doesn't apply rotation or scaling applied to the DisplayObject being drawn. I've edited my question to include this since it would be nice to support it, and my experiments with matrix scaling/rotation haven't turned out very well.

Comment: Mmm, it would just save a few lines of code if you just placed the rotated and scaled object into a holder that you draw ...

Comment: Hmm, how would I do that "placing"?

Comment: objectToBeDrawn.addChild(scaledAndRotatedObject);

Comment: I have a working implementation now. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

The way i see it you have several ways to approach this:

- **Use the graphics property of a "canvas" Shape**
  Pros: Nice and simple
  Cons: Very limited, especially if you need to remove things, since you would have to redraw the whole canvas.
- **Use a Bitmap and the .draw() method**
  Pros: Also nice and simple, and you can do duplication of things more easily.
  Cons: Basically has the same problems as the prior approach, deleting anything would need a complete redraw. Also it won't be scalable since it's a bitmap.
- **Use a Sprite and add primitives as children**
  Pros: Very flexible.
  Cons: This allows you to move, scale and delete objects individually. However, it will be slightly more complicated than the previous two options.

Using the last approach (which I would recommend if you're going to do anything more than something very small with this) your problem can be solved by using Bitmaps that you add to your "drawing", these support transparency (like you've found out) and are a bit more straightforward than using bitmapFill (which is a bit tricky to get right).

I have an example of [using a bitmap to clone and draw other DisplayObjects](http://grapefrukt.com/blog/the-need-for-stupid-amounts-of-objects/) on my blog. It's not exactly what you want but the code might be of some use, atleast the matrix part for the draw method.

Comment: I subscribe to your blog and like it very much, so I'd actually already read that article. I'm opting for the first solution because the scenario here is really "bitmap brush" - I have lineTo()s that I want to intermix with the bitmap, and no deleting is really necessary. Thanks for the other tips!

Comment: I've edited the question to include support rotation and scaling of the DisplayObject being drawn.

Answer (score 1):

bzlm - you could always make the starting X position a constant, and combine drawRect with a Matrix translate.

```
var xPos:Number = 750;
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(xPos,0);
mySprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmap,matrix);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(xPos,yPos,imgWidth,imgHeight);
```